# Screenshot from html video element to small

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently working on a project, where I have a locally hosted html page with a live video stream in it. I want to be able to capture a image from the video when pressing a button. The video is an html video element that gets its contents from hls.js. I already have a javascript function that is called when the button is clicked. The script uses a hidden canvas and sets its width and height to video.videoWidth and video.videoHeight. Then canvas.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight); is called to get an image of the video. I then get a link to the image with canvas.toDataURL('image/png'); and pass the link to the href of an  tag.

The problem is, that the resulting image always is 300x150, while the video is 1920x1080. This obviously is not what I want. I want to have an image that is the same size as the video. I dont understand whats causing this.

I have confirmed that video.videoWidth and video.videoHeight return the correct values, by printing them to console.

I am really confused, because looking on the internet and googling a lot, shows that other people are using the exact same javascript lines as I am and are apparently not having this issue.

Here is my script:

```
function MouseDown(){

        elmnt.style.backgroundColor = "black";
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var vid = document.getElementById("video");
        canvas.width = vid.videoWidth;
        canvas.height = vid.videoHeight;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(vid, 0, 0, vid.videoWidth, vid.videoHeight);
        console.log("Size: " + vid.videoWidth + "x" + vid.videoHeight);
        var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        var newimg = img.replace(/^data:image\/png/,'data:application/octet-stream');
        var a = document.getElementById("imageLink");
        a.setAttribute('download', 'Drone-Image.png');
        a.href = newimg;
        a.click();

}
```

Edit: Whatever the problem was, it resolved itself. When I started the computer that hosts the page today and tried again, it just worked...

I had tried a restart of the computer yesterday, but that didn't help...

Comment: Are you able to make a reproducible example? Because I've tried to recreate your code and it works just fine on my end. Video 1920x1080 and image also 1920x1080.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Thats exactly what I thought. For me this never works. I can try clicking on that button the whole day and it will always result in an image that is 300x150. That is really weird... I will try to use a different browser today and maybe that makes a difference for some reason. So far Ive been using Firefox.